# interpreting the fs register in a 32-bit binary running on a windows 64-bit system

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, portable-executable, malware

I have found the following code in a 32-bit binary running on a windows 64-bit system :

```
mov eax,dword ptr fs:[18]
mov ecx,dword ptr [eax+F70]
mov eax,dword ptr [ecx+78]
ret
```

it seems that it returns the win32threadinfo address but i struggle to interpret the offsets due to the confusion 32-bit/64-bit. Is this correct ?

```
mov eax,dword ptr fs:[18]    => eax = TIB address (32-bit interpretation)
mov ecx,dword ptr [eax+F70]  => F70 offset undocumented in TIB ?
mov eax,dword ptr [ecx+78]   => eax = win32threadinfo (64-bit interpretation)
```

Comment: A 32-bit app running on a 64-bit machine runs the same as when running on a 32-bit machine - everything in that process is 32 bits. What is the real issue you are facing?

Comment: The actual numeric value in the `fs` register itself (the selector) is likely to be `0` on a 64-bit kernel, since the kernel can set the FS/GS bases via an MSR (to any 64-bit value).  A 32-bit kernel probably had to make a GDT or LDT entry, since for some reason the MSR method or even `wrfsbase` don't work in 32-bit mode.  Of course, `mov eax, fs:[18]` uses the FS base, not the selector value you'd get from `mov eax, fs`, so it doesn't matter how the kernel set it up, just that fixed offsets from its base have useful data.  32-bit code should work unchanged under a 32 or 64-bit kernel.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Unfortunately, that's not true. WOW64 processes have quite a few differences with a real native 32-bit process.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot Windows (32-bit) on Windows64 has user-space differences; e.g. the DLLs far-jump into 64-bit user-space before calling into the kernel, so the kernel itself doesn't have to provide a 32-bit ABI.  (Or if it does, WOW64 doesn't use it.)  So it makes sense that there's some extra stuff to support the 64-bit user-space code in the same process.

Comment: thank you all for your explanations, it's clearer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOW64 processes have two TEBs (and two PEBS). The 32-bit TEB (TEB32) is accessible through `fs` (and its linear address at `[fs:0x18]`) in the usual way and the native 64-bit TEB (TEB64) is accessible through a pointer at offset `0xf70` in the TEB32 (see [this](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=621)) or even through `gs` and `[gs:0x30]` (though this may be version specific).

The TEB32 of a WOW64 process is not completely identical to that of a real native 32-bit process.

So, your interpretation appears to be correct.

Comment: Great ! thanks for your help Margaret
How did you find the info about the offset F70 ? all i had found was GdiBatchCount